# Problems CASTing with IEnumerator GetEnumerator()

Tags: c#

I don't fully understand all of the complexities of CASTing and Serialization and I'm having a problem with the following code generating a cast error in the second object's GetEnumerator() block of code.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated both in solving this, but also in understanding this better.  Thanks in advance.

```
[Serializable]
public class DBFieldMap
{
    public String fieldName { get; set; }
    public String fieldValue { get; set; }
    public DBFieldMap() { }
    public DBFieldMap(String fname, String fvalue)
    {
        fieldName = fname;
        fieldValue = fvalue;
    }
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return (IEnumerator)this;
    }
}
```

Second Object

```
[Serializable]
public class MappedSQLFields : Dictionary<String, DBFieldMap>
{
    public MappedSQLFields()
    {
        this.Add("clinicianstatus", new DBFieldMap());
        this.Add("researcherstatus", new DBFieldMap());
        this.Add("patientcarestatus", new DBFieldMap());
        this.Add("managerstatus", new DBFieldMap());
        this.Add("locationid", new DBFieldMap());
        this.Add("managerid", new DBFieldMap());


    }
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return (IEnumerator)this; ==>Error message  here is -Unable to cast object of type MappedSQLFields System.Collections.IEnumerator System.InvalidCastException

    }
    public MappedSQLFields(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        : base(info, context)
    {
  }
```

Main Object:

```
public Audience()
{
...
    Dictionary<String, String> fields = new Dictionary<String, String>()
       {
        {"_locationid",""},
        {"_managerid",""},
        {"_clinicianstatus",""},
        {"_managerstatus",""},
        {"_patientcarestatus",""},
        {"_researcherstatus",""},
       };

    private void loadCriteria()
    { 
        //Load values into Dictionary
        foreach (KeyValuePair<String,DBFieldMap> item in audienceSQLMap) ==>Error in stack starts here
        {
            this.fields["_"+ item.Key] = item.Value.fieldValue; 
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please use the Answer feature to add solutions. If your goal is to clarify another answer or give thanks to its author, add a comment to their answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well `DBFieldMap` does not implement `IEnumerable`, so I can see why that cast would fail.

Secondly, `MappedSQLFields` *already* implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<String, DBFieldMap>>` via its inheritance of `Dictionary<String, DBFieldMap>` so I'm not sure why you feel like you need to implement it *again*.

Comment: Okay that explains my ignorance.  I thought I always had to implement a GetEnumerable() method when an object was serializable.

Comment: @Trebor No - `GetEnumerator` is for _enumeration_ (looping), not _serialization_.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  That's helpful.  I'll have to go back to my code to see the circumstances it complains when I haven't had a GetEnumerator() method to be able to fully digest this.  Thank you again for your help and time.